# Percentage width & auto height div float bug

Tags: html, css

Have a weird bug when floating percentage width divs with auto heights. The smaller div is not level with larger div to the left of it, it's 85px lower in all browsers. I can fix it by changing the margin to negative height but the effect is different across all browers, if it's perfect in Firefox there's slight gaps in Chrome and IE, that's no good.

**DEMO**

---

```css
.wrap-outer {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrap-inner {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 92%;
  margin: -100px 4% 0px 4%;
  clear: both;
}

.large-top {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  background: #e6f0d7;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
}
.large-middle {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  background: #9ea790;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}
.large-bottom {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  background: #f8ffee;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 5px 0px 80px 0px;
}

.small-top {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 39%;
  height: auto;
  background: #e6f0d7;
  margin: 0 0 0 1%;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
}
.small-middle {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 39%;
  height: auto;
  background: #9ea790;
  margin: 0 0 0 1%;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}
.small-bottom {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 39%;
  height: auto;
  background: #f8ffee;
  margin: 0 0 0 1%;
  padding: 5px 0px 40px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-outer">
  <div class="wrap-inner">

    <div class="large-top"></div>
    <div class="large-middle"></div>
    <div class="large-bottom"></div>

    <div class="small-top"></div>
    <div class="small-middle"></div>
    <div class="small-bottom"></div>

  </div>
</div
```

I removed padding as some of my padding adds up to 85px height but it makes no difference. Also I put only these divs in a test page with nothing else and it's still the same. Anyone else had this problem?

Comment: It's really unclear what you are trying to accomplish so, I can't help you.

Comment: The divs do not align in height when floated next to each other, I'm using xhtml 1.0 strict, the snippet here works but not my end.

Comment: Some minus 1'd this question. Why? It's perfectly legitimate and I have posted an answer to it below and learned something in the process. Abusing the system is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

CSS works as designed. Your floats are placed in the following way (see section [9.5.1 "Positioning the float"](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-position) in the [CSS 2.1 Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/)):

1. `<div class="large-top">` gets floated to the left, and it takes 60% of the available width.
2. Then `<div class="large-middle">` comes and wants to float to the left. It cannot fit, because it wants 60% of the width and only 40% is available. So it gets placed under the previous `<div>`.
3. Then `<div class="large-bottom">` comes and wants to float to the left. It cannot fit, because it wants 60% of the width and only 40% is available. So it gets placed under the previous `<div>`.
4. Then `<div class="small-top">` comes and want to float to the left and it fits, because it wants 40% of the width, which is available. **The consequence is that the top of the `<div class="small-top">` gets aligned with the top of the `<div class="large-bottom">`.** The key rule is

   > The outer top of a floating box may not be higher than the outer top of any block or floated box generated by an element earlier in the source document.

   Therefore the top of `<div class="small-top">` cannot be higher than the top of `<div class="large-bottom">`.
5. Then `<div class="small-middle">` comes and wants to float to the left; due to the height of the `<div class="large-bottom">` and `<div class="small-top">` it finds place below the `<div class="small-top">`.
6. And the same for `<div class="small-bottom">`.

Comment: Nice explanation, thanks. It's good to know why it was happening. I was scratching my head when I changed the small divs to float to the right and it was still happening. My answer below will mean less code as well which is better for me.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I should have used containers around the segments and then set the segments to 100% width.

Working code below;

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.wrap-outer {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 100%;
}
.wrap-inner {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 92%;
margin: 0px 4% 0px 4%;
}

.wrap-small {position:relative; float:left; width:39%; margin-left:1%; height:100%;}
.wrap-large {position:relative; float:left; width:60%; height:100%;}

.large-top {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 100%;
background: #e6f0d7;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
}
.large-middle {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 100%;
background: #9ea790;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}
.large-bottom {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 100%;
background: #f8ffee;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
padding: 5px 0px 80px 0px;
}

.small-top {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 100%;
background: #e6f0d7;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
}
.small-middle {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 100%;
background: #9ea790;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}
.small-bottom {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 100%;
background: #f8ffee;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
padding: 5px 0px 40px 0px;
}
</style>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>


<div class="wrap-outer">
<div class="wrap-inner">

<div class="wrap-large">
<div class="large-top">dsff</div>
<div class="large-middle">sfsfd</div>
<div class="large-bottom">sdffds</div>
</div>

<div class="wrap-small">
<div class="small-top">sfdsd</div>
<div class="small-middle">sdfdsf</div>
<div class="small-bottom">sfds</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```